# This tag DOES go out of [style]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/style) tag is condemned by its own tag wiki:

> **DO NOT USE THIS TAG. This tag does not currently have a single, well-defined meaning.** It is often used in place of, or in conjunction with, [css]. It is also used on questions about the appearance of user interfaces and questions about source code formatting.

Well, there you have it - the tag's ambiguous.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No, its own Wiki admits that it's ambiguous.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Admittedly, at least *some* of the topics that this *could* refer to are on topic here, but it could refer to many things that aren't on topic at all.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Not really.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, absolutely not, its own tag usage guidance admits as much.

Unlike Taylor Swift, this tag **does** go out of [style]. Can we burninate it?

[Music video for those unfamiliar with the song I'm referring to](https://youtu.be/-CmadmM5cOk)

Comment: Who is Taylor Swift?

Comment: @rene https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_(Taylor_Swift_song) :)

Comment: It's synonymized to [tag:styles], which is where the wiki actually lives, so (a) we'd be getting rid of both and (b) the "real" tag is [tag:styles]. I acknowledge that the singular lends itself to better puns.

Comment: @rene: She invented a [programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(programming_language)) ;)

Comment: @rene She's a security expert. https://twitter.com/SwiftOnSecurity

Comment: like @PaulRoub mentioned, because it's a synonym to `styles` this would be a lot of overhaul. Also the `styles` tag has [some really good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/styles?sort=votes&pageSize=50) that I *assume* a lot of beginners look for

Comment: 6,448 questions on it currently, this will be quite a lot of work, but seems like a good fit for burnination to me.

Comment: Possible related tag that could qualify under the same criteria: [tag:themes], 5617 questions, but let's keep that one for another time (if someone feels like it, the backlog for burnination is ever growing)